# Shopify embedded app view in store admin panel not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

im new to shopify and working on a sales channel it is embedded by default and when i install this on my development store and go to my store Admin Panel i got  broken link like

> 0e5c-103-125-178-100.ap.ngrok.io refused to connect.

and in the chrome developer tools i got this

> Refused to display 'https://0e5c-103-125-178-100.ap.ngrok.io/' in a
> frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

i just want to show a welcome message to the store owner in this embedded view after the app installation.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Shopify Docs](https://shopify.dev/apps/store/security/iframe-protection#embedded-apps), you need to set up specific Content Security Policy for Embedded apps.

> If your app is an embedded app, then you need to make sure that your
> app is only frameable by the authenticated shop domain. Set the
> frame-ancestors directive dynamically based on the current shop domain
> and the Shopify admin domain. Setting this directive guarantees that
> your app can be framed only within the shop admin.

In this case, you need to add the value of **frame-ancestors** based on the authenticated store that is embedding your app.

If you use [Shopify CLI](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/cli) to generate your boilerplate code in (Node, PHP or Ruby), this should already work out of the box.

If you don't want to use the Shopify CLI, you can use [Shopify App Gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app) in your Rails application.

You can have a look at this [PR](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/pull/1474/files) to get an idea how, Shopify App Gem adds the CSP. Code snippet from that PR

```
content_security_policy do |policy |
  policy.frame_ancestors(- > do
      domain_host = current_shopify_domain || "*.myshopify.com"
    "https://#{domain_host} https://admin.shopify.com;"
    end)
end
```

Comment: Thankyou Akbar for your help may be the answer you give is right but the line below solved my issue

  response.headers.except! 'X-Frame-Options'